# Type AVCaptureDevice does not conform to protocol Sequence

Tags: swift, firebase

I am trying to open the front camera in order for talking a selfie and saving it as output still for the user to be able to see the pic before submitting. The original function I configure was depreciated at iOS 10.
Someone can help to understand how to write this correctly?

```
 //OLD CODE:
 let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devicesWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    for device in devices {

       if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front {


            do {

                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device as! AVCaptureDevice)
                if captureSession.canAddInput(input) { ... 
 //NEW CODE:   
   let devices = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: .front)
     )

    for device in devices {
        if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.front {

            do {
                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: devices)
                if captureSession.canAddInput(input) {
                    captureSession.addInput(input)
                    stillImageOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG]

                    if captureSession.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
                        captureSession.add(stillImageOutput)
                        captureSession.startRunning()

                        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                        previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
                        previewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
                        cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

                        previewLayer.bounds = cameraView.frame
                        previewLayer.position = CGPoint(x: cameraView.frame.width/2, y: cameraView.frame.height/2)

                    }
                }
            }
            catch {

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/2361508-default)

```
class func `default`(_ deviceType: AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType, 
                 for mediaType: AVMediaType?, 
            position: AVCaptureDevice.Position) -> AVCaptureDevice?
```

So the `default` method returns an optional `AVCaptureDevice`.

You just have to replace

```
//NEW CODE:   
   let devices = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: .front)
     )

    for device in devices {
        if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.front {
```

with

```
//NEW CODE:   
        if let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: .front) {
```